# Swift cannot pass class conforming to protocol as function parameter to a function residing in Objective-C file

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, parameters, protocols

Hi I'm new to Swift but experienced with Objective-C. 
I have a project that uses both Swift and Objective-C files (bridging and all).

Say I have a protocol called "fooProtocol" and a class "foo" that implements it. I am trying to pass an object of type "fooProtocol" from the Swift file as a parameter to the function inside the Objective-C file.

here is the Objective-C function inside class "tester":

`-(void)setWithFoo:(id<fooProtocol>*)_foo{
}`

here is the Swift code:

`var myObject:fooProtocol = foo.init()
 var objcObject:tester = tester.init()
 objcObject.setWithFoo(_foo: myObject)`

It first says "Cannot convert value of type "fooProtocol" to expected argument type "AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer  (obviously because it needs to be passed by reference, so...)

I then tried casting the parameter to this:

`tester.setWithFoo(_foo: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<fooProtocol>(myObject))`

Now the error reads: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer with an argument list of type '(fooProtocol)'

I have tried many more permutations and variations but I simply cannot stop the compiler error. For such a simple procedure as passing a polymorphic variable to a function in Objective-C file that expects that protocol id, Swift has made it a nightmare.

...Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

=== EDIT ===

Here are the declarations for the classes, now starting properly with caps

In the "FooProtocol.h" file:

```
@protocol FooProtocol
@end
```

In the "Foo.h" file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FooProtocol.h"

@interface Foo : NSObject <FooProtocol>
@end
```

In the "Foo.m":

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo
@end
```

The "FooProtocol.h" file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol FooProtocol
@end
```

The "Tester.h" file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FooProtocol.h"

@interface Tester : NSObject
-(void)setWithFoo:(id<FooProtocol>*)_foo;
@end
```

The "Tester.m" file:

```
#import "Tester.h"

@implementation Tester

-(void)setWithFoo:(id<FooProtocol>*)_foo{
    //do something with _foo
}
@end
```

And again the Swift code that can't compile:

```
var myObject:FooProtocol = Foo.init()
var objcObject:Tester = Tester.init()
objcObject.setWithFoo(AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<FooProtocol>(myObject))
```

Comment: Show the declarations of `fooProtocol` and `foo`. — And if you are really "experienced with Objective-C" you should know that protocol and class names should start with _capital letters_.

Comment: Declarations are in, yes you're right classes should start with capital letters

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to reproduce the issue and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't mean to say this:

```
-(void)setWithFoo:(id<FooProtocol>*)_foo;
```

It is *very* unusual to see an `id*` in Objective-C. In fact, it's so unusual that in all my years of programming Cocoa, I have *never* seen one.

You probably mean this:

```
-(void)setWithFoo:(id<FooProtocol>)_foo;
```

And then you will be able to say, on the Swift side:

```
objcObject.setWithFoo(myObject)
```

Comment: You're right that is what I in fact wanted. It will get passed by reference regardless, so I don't know why I put the asterisk. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly so. The purpose of the `*` would be allow you to _replace_ this object with a _different_ one, setting the original argument by indirection. There's rarely a need for that; only in the case of `NSError**` is it at all common (and it happens in the case of some functions and methods that effectively return more than one result).